# AbstractController::ActionNotFound - Strange error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm facing a really strange routing error that I can't seem to work out in Rails 3.2.11

The error is: AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'bulk_submissions_url' could not be found for SubmissionsController)

I have a route that looks like this:

```
match 'submissions/bulk_submissions_url' => 'submissions#bulk_submissions_url', :as => 'bulk_submissions_url', :via => :post
```

A SubmissionsController that looks like this:

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController

...
def bulk_submissions_url
    if signed_in?

      #get the cert that the user has if they are returning to tutorial
      if current_user.enrollments and current_user.enrollments.length > 0
        @enrollment = current_user.enrollments.last
      else
        #handle this
      end  

      @submission = Submission.create!(url: params[:url], description: "Please edit this description", work_type: "other", date_completed: DateTime.now.to_date)  

      if @submission.save
        @enrollment.submissions << @submission
        render :json => { success: true, submission_id: @submission.id }
      else
        render :json => { success: false }
      end

    end
end
```

And am placing a request with jQuery:

```
//save the submission
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
    url: '<%= bulk_submissions_url_path %>',
    data: {url : $("#tutorial_add_work_url_input").val()},
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using the _url on the names? that could lead to confusions since a route named my_route than can be accessed by methods like my_route_path and my_route_url, but if you name your route my_route_url, then it should be accessed by my_route_url_path and my_route_url_url which is a mess.

Try this route:

```
match 'submissions/bulk_submissions' => 'submissions#bulk_submissions', :as => 'bulk_submissions', :via => :post
```

controller:

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController

  def bulk_submissions
    if signed_in?

      #get the cert that the user has if they are returning to tutorial
      if current_user.enrollments and current_user.enrollments.length > 0
        @enrollment = current_user.enrollments.last
      else
        #handle this
      end

      @submission = Submission.create!(url: params[:url], description: "Please edit this description", work_type: "other", date_completed: DateTime.now.to_date)

      if @submission.save
        @enrollment.submissions << @submission
        render :json => { success: true, submission_id: @submission.id }
      else
        render :json => { success: false }
      end

    end
  end
end
```

and ajax

```
//save the submission
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
  url: '<%= bulk_submissions_path %>',
  data: {url : $("#tutorial_add_work_url_input").val()},
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: Exactly right, changing the name of the route to not use the _url suffix works perfectly. I meant it to be the bulk submission of urls and didn't think about the naming. Thanks!